# Is there any methods to find get custom query params in controller even using EnableRequestCaching()?

Tags: openiddict

I'm using **Angular SPA** with **IDServer**. In SPA application customers can change **the culture** but I want to change IDServer's culture for **the first login**. For example, if customers want to continue with French I have to send a parameter in customQueryParams (angular-oauth2-oidc) for their **first login**. However, I also use EnableRequestCaching in Startup.cs. I would like to get OpenIdDictRequest in **Account/Login** method.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, your users are redirected from the SPA to the IDServer with a custom query parameter containing the user's culture.

They would land at your authorization endpoint first, before being redirected to Account/Login. In the authorization endpoint you have the OpenIddictRequest at your disposal. You could send the culture from the OpenIddictRequest along with the redirect to Account/Login, through a query parameter or ViewData.